# What's the worst-case complexity for finding n/2 smallest values for different data structures?

Tags: java, time, complexity-theory, big-o

For different data structures such as linked lists, arrays (sorted/unsorted, trees etc. of size n, what is the worst-case time-complexity of finding the n/2 smallest values in each of them?
Is it the same as the complexity for Find operations?

Edit: So, what's the complexity for these data structures?
Unsorted Linked list, unsorted array, splay trees and hash tables?

Comment: Well, that would depend on the specific data structure.

Comment: It's trivial in O(n) memory and O(n*log(n)) time no matter what data structure the original data was in by inserting everything into an ordered list.

Comment: It's doable in O(n) time on any data structure that supports enumerating every element in linear time, too, using the median-of-medians algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. For instance, for a sorted array you can find the n/2 smallest values in constant time.

Answer (score 0):

It completly depends on the data structure, and wether it's sorted or not, for instance.

If you consider a balanced tree, finding the n/2 smallest values would be... "all the values to the "left" of the root.

You cannot generalize it quite as much, it depends fully on the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to specify a *worst case* complexity for a problem without specifying the algorithm, or at least the data structure. There are data structures that are an absolute nightmare to sort without using a more suitable structure for intermediate storage. Stacks, for example, are significantly harder to sort than arrays, because you cannot swap elements at random.

Combine that with an algorithm such as [BogoSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) and you can get some pretty impressive (for lack of a better word) worst case complexity figures...

Comment: I believe that the question is dealing with the general case. I would rephrase it: what would be the best achievable complexity? Sort always can be completed at O(nlogn) time. Any data structure can be traversed in O(n) time therefore it can be copied, say, to array in O(n) time. After that just apply sorting.